# How to extract multiple columns from a two dimension array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Could I have some guidance on how to extract multiple columns from a two-dimensional array like the below using JavaScript?

```
Array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
];
```

the simple methods I've seen so far using forEach or map will allow extraction of ONE column at a time, is there a way to nest it somehow to extract whichever column index one desire?

Let's say the desire output column is 1,2 and 4.

```
Output = [
  [1, 2, 4],
  [5, 6, 8],
  [9,10,12],
];
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another problem I need to resolve is how to remove a row if it's Array[i][1]=0 or empty.

Let say we have extra array elements...

```
Array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,0,15,16],
  [17, ,19,20],
  [21,22,23,24],
];
```

The desired output is now...

```
Output = [
  [1, 2, 4],
  [5, 6, 8],
  [9,10,12],
  [21,22,24],
];
```

Comment: i have no idea what you want achive, could you add your desire output?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you want as well as how you will specify what columns you want to extract?

Comment: It would help to show what you've tried and the output desired, along with a proposed function definition if that's as far as you've gotten.

Comment: You can make use of the index paramter like . array.map(elem,index,array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each row in `arr` to a new array which you can obtain by using an inner `.map()` on an array of columns/indexes which you wish to obtain. The inner map will map each index to its associated value from the row, giving you the values at each column for each row.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
];

const cols = [1, 2, 4];
const res = arr.map(r => cols.map(i => r[i-1]));
console.log(res);
```

Further details:
As you mentioned the first map exposes each inner array inside of `arr` to the inner mapping function:

```
cols.map(i => r[i-1])
```

This mapping function will loop through the indexes defined inside of `cols` and transform them into a new value. For example, say you're `r` is the second array:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Performing `cols.map(...)` will loop over each element (denoted by `i` in the callback function) in `[1, 2, 4]`. For each element, we "transform" it into a new element:

```
i = 1
r = [5, 6, 7, 8]
new value: r[1-1] = 5
```

Next iteration we look at the next value in `cols`:

```
i = 2
r = [5, 6, 7, 8]
new value: r[2-1] = 6
```

Lastly, we look at the final value in `cols`:

```
i = 4
r = [5, 6, 7, 8]
new value: r[4-1] = 8
```

So the mapping function produces a new array which transforms the values from cols `[1, 2, 4]`, into the values at those indexes in the current row to be `[5, 6, 8]`. This occurs for each inner array / row, producing the final result.

---

**EDIT**
As per your edit, you can apply the same logic from above to get your arrays with only the columns you desire. Once you have done that you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to keep only the rows which have a [truthy](https://www.google.com/search?q=truthy%20MDN&oq=truthy%20MDN&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5140j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) value in the second column. Keeping all the arrays with truthy values in the second column will remove the arrays with non-truthy values in the second column ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values) from your resulting array. `0` and `undefined` are both flasy values, so they are not kept.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,0,15,16],
  [17, ,19,20],
  [21,22,23,24],
]

const cols = [1, 2, 4];
const col = 2;
const res = arr.filter(r => r[col-1]).map(r => cols.map(i => r[i-1]));
console.log(res);
```

If you have multiple columns you want to ignore, you can use `.every()` to ensure each (ie: every) column contains a truthy value. If they all do, then `.every()` will return `true`, keeping the column, otherwise, it will return `false`, removing the column:

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,0,15,16],
  [ ,17,19,20],
  [21,22,23,24],
]

const cols = [1, 2, 4];
const col = [1, 2];
const res = arr.filter(r => col.every(c => r[c-1])).map(r => cols.map(i => r[i-1]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Works a treat!. The first map exposes each element in arr to (r => cols.map(i => r[i-1])). But exact what happens inside those brackets...a bit beyond me, are you able to help elaborate so we can better understand how it works?

Comment: @user1488934 sure, I tried to add some more details. In short, the inner `.map()` takes the values from `cols` and treats them as indexes. So for the current array `r`, it will map each index value `i` from `cols` to the value at that index from `r`

Comment: @Nick_Parsons, if we're now requiring to filter col 1 as well as 2; const col = [1,2]; , how could we implement this? I've tried const res = arr.map(r => cols.map(i => r[i-1])).filter(r => r[col.map(i => r[i-1])-1]); Also for a large data set with say 30 columns and 5000+ rows; would filter before map be more beneficial performance wise?

Comment: I've updated my answer (see last hidden code snippet). Performance for it will be N\*M + N\*K, where N = size of `arr`, M = size of `cols`, K = size of `col`. If you do the filter first, then the performance would be N\*K + X\*M, where X = size of array after the filter. In the worst case the filter won't remove any elements from your `arr`, which in that case X = N. So, you're correct. Doing the filter before the map will be more performant, as `X` will usually be less than `N`, making N\*K + X\*M <= N\*M + N\*K (so basically, using filter before the map would be more performant)

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it the below given way. The solution is using the index parameter available in filter method .

**Array.filter(currElem,index,array)**

Since array is 0-indexed ,so I created the array with index you want in the data as [0,1,3] . You need to pass the data array and index array to the function .

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9,10,11,12],
];

var arrIndex = [0,1,3];

function extractData(arr,indexArr) {

  return arr.map(obj => {  
      return obj.filter((ob,index) => {
          if(indexArr.includes(index)){return ob}
      })
  })
}

console.log(extractData(array,arrIndex));
```